# Find/replace vector element and Logit in Python-ArcMap

Tags: python, gis, arcmap

I just want to perform the following operation done in Matlab into the Field Calculator using Python:

```
p(p==0) = 0.001 ; p(p == 1) = 0.999; 
tVar = .5*log(p ./ (1 - p))
```

the operation consists of a Logit transformation:

1. Find 0's and 1's and replace with .001 and .999 respectively, and
2. Perform the second calculation with logarithms

I've tried the following for 1) in Python to no avail:

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def iLogit(a):
  return [.0001 if x==0 else x for x in a]
```

There's an error:

```
> A field name was not found or there were unbalanced quotation marks.
> ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to execute
> (CalculateField).
```

[image]

Any help please?

Comment: When you say "to no avail", what went wrong? If errors, give the traceback, if unexpected output give the inputs and expected and actual output.

Comment: I just added the error message..